# How to create a symbolic Matrix for evaluation at specific values

Tags: matrix

I want to create a symbolic matrix that I can evaluate at the given values of variables.

Definitions:

```
mat = {{1, 1 + s1, 3}, {1 + s2, 0, 6}, {5, 6, s3}};
mat1[s1_, s2_, s3_] := {{1, 1 + s1, 3}, {1 + s2, 0, 6}, {5, 6, s3}};
mat2[s1_, s2_, s3_] := mat
```

I have a very large matrix (3000, 3000) of the form `mat` with some symbols.

```
mat1[999, 777, 333]
```

produces

```
{{1, 1000, 3}, {778, 0, 6}, {5, 6, 333}}
```

which is what I want. However, if I run:

```
mat2[999, 777, 333]
```

I get the following unevaluated matrix:

```
{{1, 1 + s1, 3}, {1 + s2, 0, 6}, {5, 6, s3}}.
```

Why?

My purpose is to use matrix `mat2[...]` because I import the large matrix `mat` from an Excel worksheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mat2[s1_, s2_, s3_] = Evaluate[mat]
```

works fine, but doesn't strike me as great programming style.

There's also the more cumbersome but likely clearer:

```
mat2[ss1_, ss2_, ss3_] = mat /. {s1 -> ss1, s2 -> ss2, s3 -> ss3}
```

Finally, since you mention importing these from an Excel worksheet, perhaps something like this could work well?

```
matCSV=ExportString[mat, "CSV"];
mat2[s1_, s2_, s3_] = ToExpression[ImportString[matCSV, "CSV"]]
```

Notes:

- I'm using `matCSV` to simulate the CSV string. You could try `Import` directly with your file instead of `ImportString`.
- All the functions above used `Set` instead of `SetDelayed`, which may or may not be useful if `mat` is large enough to be expensive. They of-course work fine with `SetDelayed` as-well.

Comment: Your suggestion worked well that `ToExpression[...]` was the key to solving my problem. The answer of @Mauricio de Oliveira did not work for me, although it works in general because importing data from Excel was `The` key point you indicated. Thank you both for the help.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the way you are defining `mat2` using `SetDelayed`. Because of the `SetDelayed` (:=), the symbols `s1`, `s2`, and `s3`

```
mat2[s1_, s2_, s3_] := mat
```

are not to be found on the right-hand at the time of the assignment and do not get substituted at the time you evaluate

```
mat2[1,2,3]
```

which returns

> {{1, 1 + s1, 3}, {1 + s2, 0, 6}, {5, 6, s3}}

If you use `Set` (=), as in

```
mat2[s1_, s2_, s3_] = mat
```

the expression `mat` gets evaluate at the time of the assignment and the symbols are then substituted when you evaluate

```
mat2[1,2,3]
```

which then returns

> {{1, 2, 3}, {3, 0, 6}, {5, 6, 3}}